# ionic white screen only on ios build

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, ionic4

I made an ionic app, built successfully to serve, lab. When I built to ios after splash screen only white screen is shown and no error message is in inspector. But I found this.

[image]

file://cordova.js is not found, but the compiler build successful.

Comment: Did you find a solution please? I have the same exact issue

Answer (score 0):

The problem was, I used unsuported plugins.
Find the list in link:
https://capacitorjs.com/docs/cordova/known-incompatible-plugins